# Trying to make an unordered list split into two columns

Tags: html-lists

I'm trying to separate this ul to be two columns splitting after "Lotus Notes Administration (this is for my resume) Can someone help me with the CSS?

```
    <section>
        <h4>Technical Expertise</h4>
            <div id="skills">
    <ul>
        <li>HMTL5</li>
        <li>SQL</li>
        <li>XHTML</li>
        <li>Networking</li>
        <li>End User Training</li>
        <li>Inventory Management</li>                       
        <li>SDLC</li>
        <li>Active Directory Administration</li>
        <li>Lotus Notes Administration</li>
        <li>XML</li>            
        <li>CSS</li>     
        <li>JavaScript</li> 
        <li>PHP</li>  
        <li>SEO</li>
        <li>Technical Support</li>  
        <li>Procurement</li>
        <li>Software Testing</li>
    <li>Project Management Best Practices</li>
    <li>GPO</li>            
</ul>
</div>          

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something:

```
<div class="Skills>
  <div style="float: left; width: 50%;"><ul>List A</ul></div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 50%;"><ul>List B</ul></div>
</div>
```